# PHP MYSQL output of code into input "value"

Tags: php, html

I am trying to output code into an input value like the below:

```
 echo '<input value="'.$row['content'].'"></input>';
```

$row['content'] would include simple html, a full page code for example. With the current setup however it is breaking out of the input field and pouring into the page code.

I would like a way for it to show all HTML as text including all tags and to stay confined within the input field itself.

Thanks.

Comment: [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) is more what you need

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` you need. That will allow HTML to be readable, not rendered as elements when it breaks out of attribute/tag. `textarea` might solve the immediate issue but if someone adds `</textarea>` they can add any content to your page. e.g. `</textarea><marquee>weeeeeeee injection</marquee><script>alert("Oh no");</script><textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 echo '<textarea>'.$row['content'].'</textarea>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `htmlspecialchars_decode` by doing:

```
echo '<input value="'.htmlspecialchars_decode($row['content']).'">' ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You sure about `decode`?

Answer (score 0):

if I undersand it correctly

```
<?php echo strip_tags($row['content']) ?>
```

Comment: This would lose all HTML content.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of htmlentities() function

```
<input value="<?= htmlentities($row['content']; ?>">
```